# Set Background tint mode on a View

Tags: android

I can set bakground color of ImageView using this function :

```
imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

but when i try the same funtion on a View it doesn't work and it shows me cannot resolve method getDrawable.

I have to use View Type because i inflate Layout Resource File

```
public class game extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout Rel_main_game;
View pauseButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    Rel_main_game = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt2);

    LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    pauseButton = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.pause, null, false);
    Rel_main_game.addView(pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Here i want to make the view a little dark to show that it is pressed
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Pause.xml Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/pauseimg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pauseimgS"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

bt_slelector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white_ho"/>
```

In xml layout.

```
  android:background="@drawable/bt_slelector"
```

Or use

```
pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to make effect on view so when we press on it shows that it is pressed , I'm talking about view not imageButton and this method does not exist in View

Comment: already have OnclickListener on the view so when i try selector it doesn't work , i'm not  trying to change the hole background of view i just want to make it a little dark to be shown in pressed mode

Comment: please post full code  layout.xml and  code activity?

Comment: I Edited Post can you see any solution ?

Comment: You try use "setOnClickListener" or see answer were edited.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this handy `method` that i use on any `view` `programmatically`

```
private static StateListDrawable getStateListDrawable(int normalColor, int pressedColor) {
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(pressedColor));
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(pressedColor));
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_activated}, new ColorDrawable(pressedColor));
    states.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(normalColor));
    return states;
}
```

simply call for `API >=16` `myView.setBackground(getStateListDrawable(normalColor, pressedColor));`
for `API < 16` call `myView.setBackgroundDrawable(getStateListDrawable(normalColor, pressedColor));`

Comment: call requird API level 16 current min is 15 ??

Comment: easy, call setBackgroundDrawable()

Comment: pauseButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getStateListDrawable(0x00000001, 0x77000000));   I did this but it does not work o.O

Comment: you initialize it before you setOnClickListener or when your activity created.

Comment: hm i'm very new in android can you explain more ?

Comment: use myView.setBackgroundDrawable(getStateListDrawable(normalColor, pressedColor)); on onCreate() inside of your activity.

Comment: so i changed MinSdkVersion to 16 and Setbackground() Works, 

pauseButton.setBackground(getStateListDrawable(0x00000001, 0x77000000)); 

 I did that on Oncreate inside Activity not working !

Comment: you need to set onClick listener to ur view so that can be applied. {android.R.attr.state_pressed} {android.R.attr. state_activated} means only when the view is clickable and pressed!

Comment: you mean that i should use view.setBackround inside the method View.setOnclickListener ?